# Virtuemart show tow price in product in details and listing page

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

I have guest user and member user to purchases the product.i have two different price for user when logged.In logged user to show two price( with member price and non member price) Guest user show only non member price . is there any setting or plugins to do this.

Eg

Guest user

Product 1

Price : $50

---

Member user

Product 1

<s>Price : $50</s>

Member price : $20

Comment: No, know idea about this ?

Comment: I believe Virtuemart has a built-in function for this, called Shopper group where you can assigned several things including discount to specific user group. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I dont know how to set the price,can u provide demo link.

Comment: Also i need product based shipping cost plugins not pro version.

Answer (score -1):

you need:
- when create product, you input 2 price from backend (base + sale price)
- when show from front-end, you check condition and show them: $user->id>0

Comment: i want to show two shopper price at same time when  one of the shopper group user logged.

Comment: @uscoding:: Try to create answers with better and more extended explanations, so readers will be able to understand what they have to do.